# Rendering quietly not working if the chunk has message = FALSE

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to render an R Markdown file quietly, i.e nothing should be displayed in the console. Let `foo.Rmd` be the following file:

````
---
title: "Foo"
output: 
    html_vignette

vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Foo}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}

---

```{r}
library(survey)
```
````

Using `rmarkdown::render("foo.Rmd", quiet = TRUE)` works correctly. However, if I add `message=FALSE` to the chunk, then some messages generated by the loading of the package appear:

````
---
title: "Foo"
output: 
    html_vignette

vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Foo}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}

---

```{r, message=FALSE}
library(survey)
```
````

```
> rmarkdown::render("foo.Rmd", quiet = TRUE)
Loading required package: grid
Loading required package: Matrix
Loading required package: survival

Attaching package: 'survey'

The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':

    dotchart
```

(Note that you have to restart the session each time you add or remove `message=FALSE`, as the messages are displayed only once per session.)

Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved on [this Github issue](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/2008). In summary, there are two ways to fix this:

- `suppressMessages(rmarkdown::render("foo.Rmd", quiet = TRUE))`
- `callr::r(function() rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd"))`

Answer (score 2):

I think, it is not necessarily a "bug". `R` considers that messages should be displayed anyway. I think `quiet` argument in `render` function is working fine to suppress anything while it is sure that messages are displayed somewhere(here in `Rmarkdown` output).
But when you suppress messages in `Rmarkdown` output, printing messages in console supersedes `quiet` function, Because `R` wants to display messages in a place(could be in "output" or in "console").
A same issue about `bash chunk` had been rised in [github](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1782), and I think that is somehow similar to your issue. 
Your issue also could be rised in `knitr`  github, so `R` developers would consider changing this option.

Of course you know, One way to get rid of messages completely is using `sink` function to divert all messages to a file.  
Then you can suppress messages in "output" by `message = F` as you did, and also suppress messages in console.

```
Restarting R session...

> divert_file <- file("divert_file.txt",open ="wt")
> sink(divert_file, type = "message")
> rmarkdown::render("foo.Rmd", quiet = T)
>
```

Comment: Ok so if I understand correctly, R considers that messages must be displayed somewhere, and if it's not in the rendered file it has to be in the console, right?

Comment: In the meantime, I opened [an issue](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/2008) for this question, it seems like it is a bug (but you got the first part right)